# Echo statement printing more values than expected

Tags: php, for-loop, echo, file-get-contents

I make call to api and in the response I receive JSON in which I access the array data like so. Problem is the JSON returns 50+ objects but I only want to echo 10 of them. In the URL that I am calling I was able to add a parameter to limit the JSON response to 10 and verified that only 10 are being returned. Problem is my echo statement still prints ALL 50+ of them.

1) How is it possible that I can echo 50+ when my JSON only returns 10?

2) Is there a For Loop that I can include below that can achieve echoing only 10?

```
<?php

   $OfficeChartData = file_get_contents("http://api.xxxx...");

   if (!empty($OfficeChartData)) {
       $OfficeCharts = json_decode($OfficeChartData, true);

       foreach ($OfficeCharts['value'] as $data) {
           echo "<p>" . $data['Position']['Title'] . "</p>";
       }
   }

?>
```

Comment: How did you verify only 10 are being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like:

```
<?php

   $OfficeChartData = file_get_contents("http://api.xxxx...");

   if (!empty($OfficeChartData)) {
       $OfficeCharts = json_decode($OfficeChartData, true);
       $cnt = 0;
       foreach ($OfficeCharts['value'] as $data) {
           if($cnt==10)break;
           echo "<p>" . $data['Position']['Title'] . "</p>";
           $cnt++;
       }
   }

?>
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted after the 15 minute no-answer period! Thank you!

Comment: Hi Roberto. Exactly what I needed. Works well. I wonder why I was still able to print all of them when the response only returned 10. Weird..

Comment: Glad I could be of service!

Comment: Kind stranger thank you for downvoting! What would be the reason?

Comment: @Jgunzblazin by the way I think something is wrong with that api. My solution is more of a Ductape fix.

Comment: I didn't down vote anything. I verified the URL by reviewing the response that was received